# jQuery change doesn't work for 2 parts which are added dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of js code that can be done easier but not sure how.

The problem is that I'm using 2 calculators to calculate values...

One is active while drag n drop is usable and then it is disabled for mobile resolutions... and the second one is active only on mobile resolutions.

In any case I have this:

```
items = ['item 22', 'item 23']
output = []
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    output.push('<p>' + items[i] + '<input class="total-items" value="0" />' + '</p>');
}
$('#total-elements').html(output.join(""));
$(".total-items").change(function(e) {
    calculateTotal();
});
```

and (difference is in input part this one below has `onClick()` )

```
c = ['item 1','item 2', 'item 3']
o = []
for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    o.push('<p>' + c[i] + '<input class="total" value="0" />' + '<a href="#" class="remove-link" onClick="deleteRecord(' + i + ');" class="delete-item">x</a></p>');
}
$('#total').html(o.join(""));
$(".total").change(function(e) {
    calculate();
});
```

Code is placed inside document ready...
The problem is with that onClick part, if that (`deleteRecord()`) function is placed inside document ready, then it doesn't work (I get  ReferenceError: 'functionName' not defined... When I placed it outside  document ready and then I need to move some other parts in order to get it working but now, when I click to remove one item from the list it will remove it which is ok but then if I try to add values to use calculator it will not calculate them since that `.change()` doesn't trigger at all...

If add it like this outside of document ready,

```
$(document).change(".total", function(e) {
  calculate();
});
```

then `calculateTotal()` which is placed inside document ready won't work...

So I am not sure how to make them both to work...

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: `$(document).change(...)` ???  The issue you describe is like a scope issue but you didn't provide any relevant context regarding your code

Comment: Setting event listeners in JavaScript is always less of a headache than inline html ones.

Comment: @A.Wolff I change that part

Comment: Wait, wich is the code you are using??? Why edit question with some random code? Here `$(document).change(".total", function(){...});` is just wrong now

Comment: please find a better Title.

Comment: @A.Wolff What do you mean some random code? That is I tried and it works only for that but not for the one inside document ready... What do you mean by relevant context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> .change() doesn't trigger at all...

That because your inputs `.total-items` and `.total` are added dynamically to the DOM by javascript so you have to use event delegation **[`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** :

```
$("body").on("change", ".total", function(e) {
     calculate();
});

$("body").on("change", ".total-items", function(e) {
     calculateTotal();
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use event delegation

```
$(document).on('change',".total", function(e) {
     calculate();
});

$(document).on('change',".total-items", function(e) {
     calculateTotal();
});
```